# Complicated WHERE clause vs. merging results with UNION, which is better?

Tags: sql-server, union, where-clause

I have some heavy query to make. I can perform it in one of either two ways:

1. Combined and complicated `WHERE` clause:

   ```
   SELECT *  
   FROM Talks d  
   WHERE (d.UserId IN (SELECT SomeGuyUserId FROM Network WHERE MainUserId = @ViewerUserId AND IsX = 0 AND IsY = 0)  
   AND DATEDIFF(DAY,d.Started,GETDATE()) < 3  
   AND d.Status <= 100)  
   OR   
   (d.UserId IN (SELECT SomeGuyUserId FROM Network WHERE MainUserId = @ViewerUserId AND IsX = 1 AND IsY = 0)   
   AND DATEDIFF(DAY,d.Started,GETDATE()) < 3   
   AND d.Status <= 110)   
   ORDER BY d.UserId;
   ```
2. Two different `SELECTS` with `UNION`:

   ```
   SELECT *   
   FROM Talks d  
   WHERE (d.UserId IN (SELECT SomeGuyUserId FROM Network WHERE MainUserId = @ViewerUserId AND IsX = 0 AND IsY = 0)  
   AND DATEDIFF(DAY,d.Started,GETDATE()) < 3  
   AND d.Status <= 100)  
   UNION  
   SELECT *   
   FROM Talks d  
   (d.UserId IN (SELECT SomeGuyUserId FROM Network WHERE MainUserId = @ViewerUserId AND IsX = 1 AND IsY = 0)   
   AND DATEDIFF(DAY,d.Started,GETDATE()) < 3   
   AND d.Status <= 110)
   ```

I have three questions:

1. Which is the better way to use? (and if you can please elaborate why)
2. Is there a better way to perform this
3. In the second case, how can I sort (`ORDER BY`) the unified result (like in the first option).

PS. all tables are pretty big (> 10M records in each) and this query should be used extensively by some website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases, SQL Server is terrible at optimizing `OR`, so it is very well possible you are better off with `UNION`. But the only way to be sure, is to test both queries against a representatively big database. Use SQL Profiler to compare the metrics.

An alternative is to refactor the WHERE clause of approach 1; try to move the `OR` deeper into the expression tree, or if possible, totally eliminate it. Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Talks d
INNER JOIN Network n ON n.SomeGuyUserId = d.UserId
WHERE n.MainUserId = @ViewerUserId
AND n.IsX IN (0, 1)
AND n.IsY = 0
AND DATEDIFF(DAY, d.Started, GETDATE()) < 3
AND d.Status <= CASE n.IsX WHEN 0 THEN 100 WHEN 1 THEN 110 END
ORDER BY d.UserId;
```

Please note this query may result in duplicate records because I replaced the `IN <subquery>` with a join. This happens when duplicate combinations of `MainUserId` and `SomeGuyUserId` exist in table `Network`. If possible, use a unique constraint to avoid that situation.

Comment: Fantastic!!! The CASE solved my main concern. Thank you all for taking your time to help me, highly appreciated.

Comment: lovely way to do it. forgot you could use case in a query. nice one :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the excution plans of both queries to decide that. Two different things could happen:

- The first query results one full table scan on `Talks`, while the
  second query results in two full table scans (one for each part of the union). In that case, the first
  query is probably faster.
- The first query results one full table scan on `Talks`, while the
  second query results in two index range scans. In that case, the
  second query is probably faster.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your first sql-query is not very complex. Compared to all the queries i've seen over the years it is in fact a simple one... i would just extract the DATEDIFF and go with that ...

```
SELECT *  
FROM Talks d  
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,d.Started,GETDATE()) < 3  
and (    (d.UserId IN (SELECT SomeGuyUserId FROM Network WHERE MainUserId = @ViewerUserId AND IsX = 0 AND IsY = 0) AND d.Status <= 100)  
     OR   
         (d.UserId IN (SELECT SomeGuyUserId FROM Network WHERE MainUserId = @ViewerUserId AND IsX = 1 AND IsY = 0) AND d.Status <= 110)   
    )
ORDER BY d.UserId;
```